# A function that can both compose and chain (dot notation) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash, ramda.js

I'm trying to convert an old api that uses a lot of dot notation chaining which needs to be kept ie:

```
[1,2,3,4].newSlice(1,2).add(1) // [3]
```

I'd like to add the functional style of composition in this example Ramda but lodash or others would be fine:

```
const sliceAddOne = R.compose(add(1), newSlice(1,2)) 
sliceAddOne([1,2,3,4])// [3]
```

My question is how can I do both chaining and composition in my function `newSlice` what would this function look like?

I have a little [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/vehideruza/2/edit?js,console) example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT

I think I initially misunderstood you. You want a function `f` that you can call as

```
f(...args)(someObj) ===  someObj.f(...args)
```

I would do that like this

```
// infix
Array.prototype.newSlice = function(x,y) { return this.slice(x,y) }

// prefix 
const newSlice = (x,y) => F => F.newSlice(x,y)
```

This is a good design because you can implement `newSlice` on any Object you wish to have `newSlice` capability on and the prefix function will just work. This also allows you to have a unique implementation of `newSlice` on each object type (Array, String, Other...) as it's likely that the underlying data we are slicing will be different – You get all of this *without* having to do silly conditional `this` checks within the body of your function.

```js
// newSlice :: [a] -> (Integer,Integer) -> [a]
Array.prototype.newSlice = function(x,y) {
  return this.slice(x,y)
}

// newSlice :: String -> (Integer,Integer) -> String
String.prototype.newSlice = function(x,y) {
  return this.substring(x,y)
}

// even on a custom object
class LottoTicket {
  constructor(...nums) { this.nums = nums }
  newSlice(x,y) { return this.nums.slice(x,y) }
}

// newSlice :: (Array, String) a => (Integer,Integer) -> a -> a
const newSlice = (x,y) => F => F.newSlice(x,y)

// use it in prefix position
console.log(newSlice(1,2)([1,2,3,4]))              // [2]
console.log(newSlice(1,2)("abcd"))                 // 'b'
console.log(newSlice(1,2)(new LottoTicket(9,8,7))) // [8]

// use it infix position
console.log([1,2,3,4].newSlice(1,2))                // [2]
console.log("abcd".newSlice(1,2))                   // 'b'
console.log((new LottoTicket(9,8,7)).newSlice(1,2)) // [8]
```

Comment: thanks for the pointer, it's why I tend to use ramda as all function are curried :)

Comment: @cmdv I appear to have mistook your initial intentions. I've reworked my answer with a new understanding.

Comment: thank you, very thorough and plenty for me to take away

Comment: with your answer i would have to add new prototypes to Array + String what would be a way to keep this inline in the function it self? I have 100 odd functions that I need to convert like this and worry with name clashing.

Comment: @cmdv aren't they all defined on the prototypes now?

Comment: They are all on a global, Global.prototype.slice, but wanted to ES6 export and isolate the functions rather than being dependent on parent child. I'm going to go with your solution http://jsbin.com/gihepevaxe/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Do you mean `Object.prototype.slice` ?

Comment: well right now it looks like this: `$Glob.prototype['splice'] = function (index, count)..` hence they need a lot of cleaning up :P